# Support for iOS 7 and iOS 8 SizeClasses

Tags: ios

We are moving towards using SizeClasses. To support iOS 7 users we need both SizeClasses and not. I can see [Apple describe the solution](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html) to use two nib files.

How to do this, in code or is it build in to load the right nib file?